# Get one item from a list in parent scope

Tags: angularjs

I have the following Angular controllers:

```
function TagListController($scope) {
  $scope.model = {
    tags: ['tag 1', 'tag 2', 'tag 3' ],
    template: 'list'
  }  
  $scope.showTemplate = function (template) {
    $scope.model.template = template;
  };
}

function TagEditController($scope) {
  $scope.tagToEdit = $scope.$parent.model ???
}
```

And I have the following HTML to show a list of tags and to edit a tag:

```
<ul ng-if="model.template == 'list'" ng-controller="TagListController">
  <li data-ng-repeat="tag in model.tags">
    <span data-ng-bind="tag.name"></span></br>
    <a href="" data-ng-click="show('edit')"</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="edit">
  <div ng-controller="TagEditController">
    Edit template
  </div>
</script>

<div ng-if="model.template == 'edit'" ng-include="'edit'"></div>
```

Using model.template I am able to show the Edit template.

But how can I, in `EditTagController`, use the tag which Edit link was clicked?

I know it will be one of the items in `$scope.$parent.model.tags.`

I just don't know how to select it and the best way to select it.

Comment: But do I need to have a scope variable tag on the parent scope or can i pass that tag to the nested controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a good place to use a `factory` or `service`.

See [this jsBin](http://jsbin.com/mejudojoma/1/edit?html,js,output)

You want to store common data inside of your factory instead of dealing with `$parent` or `$rootScope`.

You could create a factory like this:

```
function tagService() {
  var observerCallbacks = [];

  var currentTag;

  function getCurrentTag() {
    return currentTag;
  }

  function setCurrentTag(tag) {
    currentTag = tag;
    notifyObservers();
  }

  function notifyObservers() {
    angular.forEach(observerCallbacks, function(callback) {
      callback();
    });
  }

  function registerObserverCallback(callback) {
    this.observerCallbacks.push(callback);
    notifyObservers();
  }

  return {
    getCurrentTag: getCurrentTag,
    setCurrentTag: setCurrentTag,
    registerObserverCallback: registerObserverCallback,
    notifyObservers: notifyObservers
  };
}
```

Here, I'm also using the `observer` pattern to notify anybody who is listening for changes any time `setCurrentTag` is called.  That way, if you change tags, both controllers know.

Your `TagListController` might look like:

```
function TagListController($scope, tagService) {
  $scope.model = {
    tags: ['tag 1', 'tag 2', 'tag 3' ],
    template: 'list'
  };

  $scope.editTag = function(tag) {
    tagService.setCurrentTag(tag);
    $scope.model.template = 'edit';
  };
}
```

And your `TagEditController` like:

```
function TagEditController($scope, tagService) {
    tagService.registerObserverCallback(function() {
    $scope.tagToEdit = tagService.getCurrentTag();
  });
}
```

Comment: In fact I have a service but just to get or send data to the server ... Never used your approach.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Angular routing? You could set up a route like "yourapp/tags/{tag}" to your EditTagController and that way you will get the current tag as a parameter.

[Something like this](http://embed.plnkr.co/DBSbiV/preview)